# How to correctly move a server inside a rack up and down

Tags: hardware, datacenter, best-practices, rack, rackmount

Maybe a bit stupid question, but

Sometimes (rarely but it happens) I need to move a server in a rack 1-2U up or down. What do you think, which of the ways is the most correct and useful and why?

- remove a server from the rails, detach a rails, attach them back to the new place, put a server back on the rails
- carefully, hole by hole (or by 2-3 in one step if possible) move a rails together with a server
- do everything in some other way (explain)

Please do not write "you must plan a rack before assembling" etc. This is good idea to plan everything but unfortunately the real life is not so ideal :)

Comment: I see there's already one close vote on this but I feel this is a good question that most admins will encounter sooner or later.

Comment: thanks, personally I see it's always the best way to solve - remove a server then move a rails, I agree with this and recommend doing this way always when possible (except maybe a few rare circumstances i.e. the server is very heavy and nobody can help you to remove it; or you can't turn off a server right now but need to move it asap etc.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

While time-consuming, removing everything altogether and putting it back in the new location is the best way to move a server.  Trying to take shortcuts will only risk bending your rails, making them unusable.  (Bent rails are hard - if not impossible - to bend back.)

Never mind the possibility of dropping your server outright, possibly damaging yourself, the floor, or other servers!

This is also a good time to fix your cable management if it's sloppy...

Also, since you should be taking an outage on the server (you *are* shutting it down, aren't you?), it may be a good time to do those things that you don't otherwise have time for, like firmware updates?

Comment: +1 Moving equipment *in* *situ* is an honest, royal, PITA.

Comment: +1 Sometimes there's only one option that makes any sense, as many of us have already learned the hard way.

Comment: +1 Break out the Velcro tape and fix that cabling!

Comment: @Chris S: +1 for hook-and-loop tape... Stay the heck outta my racks with those damned zip-ties. I carry a pair of dikes in my backpack at all times.

Comment: While dikes are a commonly known tool, I am forced to refer to them as diagonal cutters for fear of misunderstanding and dirty looks for not being politically correct. :(

Comment: @entens: When confronted with this situation, I remind people that the tool is spelled with an "i" not "y".

Comment: Does the spelling matter?  The name isn't that common or descriptive...

Comment: @jscott: I haven't heard them called dikes in a long time (ah... memories). I usually refer to them as side cutters.